# Fatal error when add a record to WordPress table

Tags: php, wordpress

i get this error when i try to add a record from my function any suggestions to resolve this?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function insert() on a non-object
```

My function is this

```
function setdb($email){
        global $wpdb;           
        $set_mail=$email;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'nd_tempemails';
        $result=$wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array('email'=>$set_mail
            )
        );
}
```

*Edit i added my whole php code due to request.here i am sending a link and for that i am keeping the email i sent the link as a record.

```
function sendmail()
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $passmail=md5($email);
    $subject = 'The Registration Link';
    $headers = "From: xxx@xxx.xx ". "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: xxx@xxx.xx" . "\r\n".    
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();  
    $message = 'Here is your One time URL<br>';
    $message.="<a href='link";
    $message.=$passmail;
    $message.="'>click here</a>";
    mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
    setdb($passmail);
}
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
    sendmail();

}
```

all functions are in same file.

Comment: remove comma after 'email' => $set_mail inside your array passed to insert

Comment: Sorry its a mistake when i add code here.re edited the question.Do i need to include any file into this??

Comment: You have declared the $wpdb as global so it shouldn't throw this error. strange for me.

Comment: Looks ok (as @Maha Dev says, you've declared `$wpdb` as global).  How are you calling the function?

Comment: this is a function i wrote to add a record to my db when i send an email to a user so i call this function inside the function i need to send mail like setdb($passmail); is it ok? the both functions are in same php and the mail function triggered when the mail address is passes as a Post.if(isset($_POST['email'])){ sendmail();
  
}

Comment: can you include in your post above how you are using `setdb()`?

Comment: Hello i've edited the question all the code is in the same php file! Do i need to include any file in WordPress??

Comment: someone has down vote this still no comment made :( i did my study! may be not enough but guide is most needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved this by directly calling wordpress config file and using default `mysqli` commands.I tried to include wp-db.php and get this done but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function setdb($email){
        global $wpdb;       
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'nd_tempemails';
        $result=$wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array('email'=>$email)
        );
}

Call setdb('xyz@xyz.com');
```

Comment: this is a function i wrote to add a record to my db when i send an email to a user so i call this function inside the function i need to send mail like setdb($passmail); is it ok? the both functions are in same php and the mail function triggered when the mail address is passes as a Post.if(isset($_POST['email'])){ sendmail(); }